# collecting multiline logs from AWS EKS on fargate

Tags: logging, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

I have an EKS cluster running entirely on Fargate, And Im collecting its logs using aws-for-fluent-bit integration and outputting them to cloudwatch.
I want to concatenate multiline logs, but I cannot seems to find away for it.
I saw that its in the aws container roadmap:
https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1326

is there any way to collect the multiline logs? maybe using a different agent or some third party tools?

I look at FireLens but apparently its only for ECS.
I tried using fluentbit filter for [Multiline](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/multiline-stacktrace) but apparently aws-for-fluent-bit doesn't support it.

this is the fluentbit configuration:

```html
Data
====
output.conf:
----
[OUTPUT]
    Name cloudwatch_logs
    Match   *inst-dataservice*
    region eu-west-1
    log_group_name inst-dataservice-logs
    log_stream_prefix from-
    log_key log
    auto_create_group true

parsers.conf:
----
[PARSER]
    Name        docker
    Format      json
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z
    Decode_Field_as escaped_utf8 log
```

Comment: can you share your task and your fluent bit configuration?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I'v added my fluent bit configuration to the main question, what do you mean by task?

Comment: O sorry i meant ECS task but you are using EKS

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/administration/configuring-fluent-bit/multiline-parsing#configuration-example

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari thank you but it does not, since aws-for-fluent-bit integration doesnt support configurable multiline parsing, and the built-in java parser they Claim that work now still does not work in aws